# Django waiting for another server synchronously to return a response?

Tags: django, node.js, architecture

When client asks for `/some/path` to django server.

Django server asks for something to another server, for instance a node.js server.

Upon receiving data from the node.js server, django returns HTML to client.

Is something like this ok?

(well if I think about it, database is some kind of server django is talking to.. but just feeling weird I guess)

- Edit

I'm trying to use rendr.js as a rendering engine..
https://github.com/rendrjs/rendr/issues/433

I am trying to give data/html to render.js and get back rendered html to serve a client.

Comment: Your question is not really formed according to SO spec.. and I think you answered it yourself in the end - backend code will frequently talk to DBs and other APIs, so that's quite normal. If it's the best solution for your application we can't tell.

Comment: @Martin: I added what I'm trying to do specifically...

Comment: Well, again, if it makes sense for your app - go for it. Though what I notice is that you're using a client-oriented rendering library (rendr.js) on server-side. Why not just grab whatever it is your node.js API returns to you and render it with a django template?

Comment: I'm doing client rendering for faster interaction response, and it has drawback of slow loading time. rendr solves it by rendering template on server side, and hook it up in client.

Comment: I don't get it, you're using a client-side library to render on server-side and then send the rendered html back to the client. I mean.. if you really like render.js that much that you prefer it to django templates or whatnot, then fine.. or if you also sometimes use it client-side and don't want to duplicate your teamplates, that also makes sense.. but otherwise probably less so?

Comment: @Martin: it renders on the serverside, and binds event/model/view on the client side, so that users can interact with the server-rendered page.

Comment: OK, then it's reasonable enough I suppose? :)

Comment: @Martin I'm worried about the performance impact that it might incur during the django <-> server communication.

Comment: I couldn't comment on that without knowing more details.. Like I said, it's normal to access local and 3rd party databases/APIs during a server response, so there's nothing weird about it. As it's your own node server, obviously make sure it's in the same network etc. to keep latency down, but other than that it might be a perfectly valid solution.